# Kubernetes accesses pod with HostIP:Port via service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I noticed when accessing the Kubernetes Service, the host ip is ignored by the kubernetes.

For example: I have 3 kubernetes workers, `hostIP1`, `hostIP2` and `hostIP3`, on each worker, i create a pod, with label: `app = test`. In each pod, it just simple runs `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 32000`, I then create a service to expose port: `32000` so that it can be accessed outside the cluster.

But when I access `http://hostIP1:32000`, the traffic is actually routed to any of the hosts, `hostIP1`, `hostIP2` and `hostIP3`

Is there a way to only let Kubernetes forward traffic to `hostIP1` when accessing `http://hostIP1:32000`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. If your pods have the same label, they are going to be selected by the same service, and every time you hit that service it is going to balance the load among the backends it has, which are your pods.

To do what you want, you have to create 3 different services, to point each service to its own backend.

Comment: thanks. I figured out a way to do so with `containerPort` and `hostPort` so that the port is only local to the worker node
```
    ports:
    - containerPort: 32000
      hostPort: 32000
    - containerPort: 32001
      hostPort: 32001
```